# Rspec how to delete test database between each _spec file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have tests that each use FactoryGirl to build an object.  However, these objects are persisting across each _spec file and I can't get the database to clean.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: have you looked at [`database_cleaner`](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner). This should od exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I was hoping to use Rspec to accomplish this, is that not possible?

Comment: What kind of objects are persisted ? Are they the ones that come from inside the test or outside (for example in a `before(:each)` block) ?

Comment: I am currently not using any before or after blocks.  They are FactoryGirl objects.

Comment: if you are running with `transactional_fixutres = true` there should not be anything persisting between specs.